# How to number the same URL?

Tags: linux, android, rename

I would like to know if there is a way or tool that creates the same URL, but numbered by numbers, for example I want to number the same URL until I reach `2866`.ts:

```
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/884.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/885.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/886.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/887.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/888.ts
... 
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2866.ts
```

To create a .txt with all of these URLs

Is there a way to do this without having to rename one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Bash script would do this.

```
for i in {884..2866}; do echo https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/$i.ts; done
```

Output:

```
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2859.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2860.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2861.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2862.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2863.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2864.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2865.ts
https://vod-secure.twitch.tv/4eecc1c67258e07bc38b_alanzoka_28367710912_841652096/chunked/2866.ts
```

If you want to have this go into a file, add a `>> filename.txt` after the `echo`.

Comment: Mikey T.K. Thanks!!  that's what i was looking for, thanks.